# Pyspark: ValueError

Tags: pyspark

I have a dictionary of PySpark RDDs and am trying to convert them to data frames, save them as variable and then join them.  When I attempt to convert one of my RDDs to a data frame I get the following error:

```
File "./spark-1.3.1/python/pyspark/sql/types.py",     
line 986, in _verify_type
"length of fields (%d)" % (len(obj), len(dataType.fields)))
ValueError: Length of object (52) does not match with length of fields (7)
```

Does anyone know what this exactly means or can help me with a work around?

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

I agree - we need to see more code - obfuscated data is fine.

You are using SparkQL it seems (sql types) - mapped onto what ? HDFS/Text

From the error it would appear that your create schema is incorrect - leading to an error - when to create a Data Frame.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to the passing of an incorrect RDD, sorry everyone. I was passing the incorrect RDD which caused didn't fit the code I was using.